# Error husky simulation in ros noetic

Tags: ros, gazebo, husky

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, i am using husky navigation in ros noetic according to this tutorial [husky navigation tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/husky_navigation/Tutorials/Husky%20Move%20Base%20Demo). However, when i run the command `roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_playpen.launch`, it always shows the error like this

```
[spawn_husky_model-10] process has died [pid 2730237, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/noetic/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_model -x 0.0 -y 0.0 -z 0.0 -Y 0.0 -unpause -urdf -param robot_description -model / __name:=spawn_husky_model __log:=/home/ngochuy/.ros/log/04cddd9a-4078-11ec-95fc-204ef60a0173/spawn_husky_model-10.log].
log file: /home/ngochuy/.ros/log/04cddd9a-4078-11ec-95fc-204ef60a0173/spawn_husky_model-10*.log
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue, please!
Thanks in advance, and have a nice day!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390306/error-husky-simulation-in-ros-noetic/) by [N.N.Huy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52680/n.n.huy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2021-11-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-11-08**:
I'm sorry to have to do this for something seemingly minor, but please don't post screenshots of terminal text or source code in question on ROS Answers. It's all text, so there is no need. Just copy-paste the text from the terminal or the source into your question text. Do make sure to format it properly by selecting the text and pressing `ctrl+k` (or clicking the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it)).

You don't need to post a new question, just edit your curent one. You can use the `edit` button/link for this.

After you replace the screenshot with the error message itself, we can re-open your question.

**Comment by [N.N.Huy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52680/n.n.huy/) on 2021-11-08**:
Ok thank you!

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-08**:
Hi @N.N.Huy that's old tutorial. Try installing navigation package: `sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-husky-navigation`

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-08**:
For Husky more recent tutorials, check this: https://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/kinetic/husky/HuskyMove.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use a more recent version of Husky tutorial
https://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/kinetic/husky/HuskyMove.html

install the simulator from the most recent Noetic version.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-husky-simulator
sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-husky-desktop
```

For `HUSKY MOVE BASE DEMO` you also need to install:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-husky-navigation
```

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [N.N.Huy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52680/n.n.huy/) on 2021-12-30**:
Thank you so much !